# iPad can't find current location

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mkmapview

I am displaying current location for iPad in map view for this i am using following code

```
 if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) 
{
    lm = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    lm.delegate = self;
    lm.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    lm.distanceFilter = 100.0f;
    [lm startUpdatingLocation];

}
```

and i am calculating lat and longitude and passing it the url as

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?z=15&daddr=%@@%@,%@&saddr=%@@%@,%@",n,lat_New,lng_New,currentLocation,currentLatt,currentLong];
```

I am not getting the correct direction for initial starting point and ending point for iPad in map view.

Is there anything alternative for showing correct initial and staring point in iPad map view? 
Does app store rejects apps for such problems and Pleas suggest me some good alternative for this.

Comment: What do you mean by **Correct initial starting point and ending point**?

Comment: starting point is the starting position of iPad and ending point is the nearby distance showing in app

Comment: du you check the accuracy while receiving location updates?.. (e.g. check if accuracy is increasing inside a time range of ~5 sec.)

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed how you were setting your variables   lat_New,lng_New,currentLocation,currentLatt and currentLong.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things .One simulator cannot give you  GPS locations.Secondly Usually gps coordinates returned first time may not be accurate.so try receiving location updates by implementing the delegate.